# Massive performance loss by Expanding Openmp with MPI

Tags: c, performance, mpi, openmp

First, I am new to this board, so please correct me if I am doing something wrong. Now, my question:

I am trying to write a hybrid mpi/openmp matrix multiplication program. My first step was to optimise the matrix multiplication on a single node using OPENMP. This worked quite well and I archieved a performance of around 3GFLOPS. The program basically looks like:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <emmintrin.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
int main (int argc, char** argv){
   init_matrices(A,B,C);
   t_start=timer();
   mm(A,B,C);  // Matrix multiplication using OPENMP
   t_end = timer();
   t_delta = t_end - t_start;
   printf("time elapsed: %lf\n", t_delta*1.0e-9); 
}
```

There are 4 Threads created by OPENMP in mm. Now, I try to scale it to a cluster system of n nodes. My first step was just to include the MPI environment and change nothing else and test the code on one node. It looks like

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <emmintrin.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "mpi.h"
int main (int argc, char** argv)
{   
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    double t_start, t_end, t_delta;
    init_matrices(A,B,C);
    t_start = timer();
    mm(A, B, C);                
    t_end = timer();
    t_delta = t_end - t_start;
    printf("time elapsed: %lf seconds\n", t_delta*1.0e-9); 
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

I compile both codes with a Gcc 4.3.2 compiler and the command

```
mpicc -o mm mm.c -O3 -fopenmp -lm
```

and run with ./mm , -prun -np 1 ./mm

Now, I experience a massive performance loss. The speed goes down to 1.7GFLOPS (the time almost doubles). How is this possible? I don't even use communication this far. I expected that the performance remains the same. Has anyone an idea?

Comment: SO hosts many questions such as yours, asking for explanations for  performance differences between program versions.  Too many of them, on further enquiry, turn out to be based on miscalculation.  Give us some data to convince us that this is not the case for your question.

Comment: I totally understand your point. But as I said, I didnt change anything else in the code except those 3 lines I posted, i.e. added the "mpi.h" library, added the MPI_INIT(..) and MPI_Finalize(). For the time, I use clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME,&ts);. I don't want to post the complete code since its a competition, but if nobody can help me, then I will have to post a simplified version.

Comment: Sorry for the double post. But there is one more thing, I observed. For some reason, the normal OpenMp version is creating 4 threads (on a dual core computer) whereas the MPI version is only creating 2 threads. Setting the number of threads to 4 in the Mpi version does not help me performance though ... How is this possible? Is it related to Hpyerthreading?

Comment: Strictly speaking you should initialise MPI with support for multithreading, at least to the `MPI_THREAD_FUNNELED` level: `MPI_Init_thread(&argc, &argv, MPI_THREAD_FUNNELED, &supported);`. Other that that, your MPI launch command seems incomplete. Please fix your post and show the actual command. Also make sure that `mpicc` indeed uses the same version of GCC with `mpicc --showme` and `mpicc -v`.

Comment: This might come as a really stupid question but is your MPI code running on the same node (or on a node with the same hardware characteristics) as the original OpenMP program?

Comment: Please also consider that a modern Processor is able to execute a matrix multiplication with > 100 GFLops. 3 GFLops is not good performance unless you are running on a smartphone. You should investigate that before considering MPI. If you want performance, use a properly optimized parallel math library like Scalapack/MKL etc. If you want to learn, thats fine, but for real applications you will not get the performance provided by optimized libraries.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I found the error. Using ./ uses all CPUs on the current node (2 in our case of a dual core). Using prun just takes one CPU per node, so only one in this case. Thanks for all help.

Comment: Hmmmph, another performance question that turns out to be based on miscalculation, specifically a failure to compare like with like.